# Can Celery routing be used to for a specific host?

Tags: routes, celery

Celery has a better task language than saltstack, however it seems to lack machine specific routing. Is it possible to route a Celery task to a specific machine ?

Edit: The assumption is that there are hundreds or a few thousands of machines, which are provisioned (started/stopped) dynamically. So there is no way to know the name of the machine in advance

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901516/creating-queues-dynamically-with-celery

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882826/celery-dynamic-queue-creation-and-routing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thats super easy with just the default automatic routing. If you want 1 task to be rooted to one specific machine, just add a unique queue name in the task decorator, like so:

```
# tasks.py
@task(queue='my_unique_queue')
def web_site_status(url):
    return requests.get(url).status_code
```

Then with the remote box, just include the name of the queue to consume when firing up celeryd/workers.

```
$ python manage.py celeryd -l info -Q my_unique_queue
```

All remote boxes can "consume" one or more queues, so with just naming individual tasks with unique queues you can assign the tasks to all, groups of, or individual remote boxes.

Also have a look @ the docs on "manual routing" if you need even more control:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#manual-routing

Comment: Could the Q name be a task parameter to adjust for dynamic machine provisioning? Also if a machine is terminated, would that cause a memory leak in the broker as more and more unused queus pile up?

Comment: The example i posted above has queue name as parameter for the task decorator. For dynamic node provisioning there is heaps of exchange & routing parameters. But the default automatic routing is surprising good at gracefully picking up new nodes & restarting after network issues, etc. Can't comment on memory leaks with rabbitmq or redis, I've always had multiple nodes consuming off each queue.

Comment: Where can I find a code sample for that routing parameter you mention?

Comment: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html   http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/index.html

Comment: looking at other SO answers, the right approach is to use one exchange with multiple queues, and apply_async